# VS 2013 Application Insights

Tags: visual-studio-2013, azure-application-insights

I configured Application Insights to my WCF Web Role and deployed it on Azure Cloud Services.
I could see all other dashboards except Performance Dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

yes you are right. the performance dashboard is hidden.
For making it visible open management portal of azure
 go to yourcloudservice > configure > scroll down a bit > under (developer analytics) performance setting off|ADD-ON-|CUSTOM

hope it helped

[image: look for something like this]

Comment: I dont see that item in Configure page of Cloud Service

Comment: ok will see to it and keep u updated if i find anything useful

Comment: There's a performance dashboard in AppInsights. Are you looking for that one?